# How to count how many the non-zero value in a row in 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, average

How can I calculate how many non-zero values include in a row

I try to calculate the average of the total value inside a row but somehow it is always dividend in 5
How can I create a counter to count how many non-zero value inside the array?

Sorry for my bad english

```
int main () 
{
    float Sum, average;

    float a[4][5] = { {2.30,4.00,5.00},
                      {3.00,2.10,1.00,4.00},
                      {1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00},
                      {4.00,2.50}};
    int rows, columns;
    int length;
 
 
    for(rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
    {
        Sum = 0;
        for(columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++)
        {
        
            Sum = Sum + a[rows][columns];
        }
        
        printf("The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  %.2f \n", Sum );
        average = Sum / columns;
        printf("Product %d : %f\n",rows + 1,average);
    }
    

      
      return 0;
   }
```

The output cames out is:

```
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  11.30
Product 1 : 2.260000
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  10.10
Product 2 : 2.020000
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  15.00
Product 3 : 3.000000
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  6.50
Product 4 : 1.300000
```

But I was aspect it will comes out

```
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  11.30
Product 1 : 3.77
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  10.10
Product 2 : 2.53
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  15.00
Product 3 : 3.00
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  6.50
Product 4 : 3.25
```

Comment: What have you tried to add this counter? You already access all elements of a row, what's wrong with checking the value in the same place, i.e. in your inner loop?

Comment: When creating the average, you're dividing by `columns`, which is always going to be `5` upon loop exit.  You need to divide by the number of non-zero values in the row.  So create a new counter, initialize it to zero, and add one to it whenever the value in a row is non-zero.  Then divide the sum by that new counter to find the average.

Comment: OT, you probably want to print Average instead of Product

Answer (score 1):

For starters declare variables in minimal scopes where they are used. For example the variables `Sum` and `average` are used within the for loops. So they should be declared in the scope of the outer for loop.

The variable `length` is not used in the program. So remove its declaration.

Do not use magic numbers like `4` or `5`. Instead use named constants.

As for your problem then just introduce one more variable within loops that will count the number of non-zero elements in a row.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    enum { ROWS = 4, COLS = 5 };
    float a[ROWS][COLS] = 
    { 
        { 2.30, 4.00, 5.00 },
        { 3.00, 2.10, 1.00 ,4.00 },
        { 1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00 },
        { 4.00, 2.50 }
    };
        
    for ( size_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++ )
    {
        float Sum = 0.0f;
        size_t total = 0;
        
        for ( size_t col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            if ( a[row][col] != 0 )
            {   
                Sum += a[row][col];
                ++total;
            }
        }
        
        printf( "The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  %.2f \n", Sum );
        float average =total == 0 ? 0.0f :  Sum / total;
        printf( "Product %zu : %.2f\n", row + 1, average );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  11.30 
Product 1 : 3.77
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  10.10 
Product 2 : 2.53
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  15.00 
Product 3 : 3.00
The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  6.50 
Product 4 : 3.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
int main () 
{
    float Sum, average;

    float a[4][5] = { {2.30,4.00,5.00},
                      {3.00,2.10,1.00,4.00},
                      {1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00},
                      {4.00,2.50}};
    int rows, columns, nonZeroCount;
    int length;
 
 
    for(rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
    {
        Sum = 0;
        nonZeroCount = 0;
        for(columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++)
        {
            if(a[rows][columns] != 0)
                nonZeroCount++;
            Sum = Sum + a[rows][columns];
        }
        
        printf("The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  %.2f \n", Sum );
        average = Sum / nonZeroCount;
        printf("Product %d : %f\n",rows + 1,average);
    }
      return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is a solution that you are looking for:

```
int counter_row(float row[5], int n){
    int count=0;
//row vaiable is the row array
    for (auto i=0; i<n; i++){
         // loop each element of row and check it's not equal to 0, if true then increase the count
        if (row[i]!=0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }    
    return count;
}
```

You can use it:

```
int main () 
{
    float Sum, average;

    float a[4][5] = { {2.30,4.00,5.00},
                      {3.00,2.10,1.00,4.00},
                      {1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00},
                      {4.00,2.50}};
    int rows, columns;
    int length;
 
 
    for(rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
    {
        Sum = 0;
        for(columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++)
        {
            Sum = Sum + a[rows][columns];
        }
        
        printf("The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  %.2f \n", Sum );
        
        int amount = counter_row(a[rows], 5);
        average = Sum / amount;
        printf("Product %d : %f\n",rows + 1,average);
  }
    

   return 0;
}
```

another solution

```
int main () 
{
    float Sum, average;

    float a[4][5] = { {2.30,4.00,5.00},
                      {3.00,2.10,1.00,4.00},
                      {1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00},
                      {4.00,2.50}};
    int rows, columns;
    int length;
 
 
    for(rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
    {
        Sum = 0;
        // init amount variable
        int amount=0;
        for(columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++)
        {
           // condition for increase amount variable is it's not equal to 0, because we counting non-zero element
          // a[rows][columns] being element of the row needed count
            if (a[rows][columns]!=0)
                amount++;
            Sum = Sum + a[rows][columns];
        }
        
        printf("The Sum of rows Elements in a Matrix =  %.2f \n", Sum );
        // finally, amount variable is non-zero amount
        average = Sum / amount;
        printf("Product %d : %f\n",rows + 1,average);
    }
    

      return 0;
   }
```

have a nice day!!!

Comment: This is what I look for , can I have more explain for the line of if (a[rows][columns]!=0)
                amount++;
            Sum = Sum + a[rows][columns];

Comment: Im not sure whats the theory behind it

Comment: You provided 2 versions of working code, but failed to explain what did and why. So this is a code only answer which is frowned upon on SO. You should explain that you a building a counter that is increased for non null value somewhere in your answer... Not downvoted because it is almost evident, but not upvoted either ;-)

Comment: I have added some comments in my code, I think that can help you,

Answer (score 0):

Your example suggests that the non-zero values are first in the array. If that is true you can stop the loop at the first value being zero.

Change

```
columns < 5
```

to

```
columns < 5 && a[rows][columns] != 0
```

BTW... You should check that columns isn't zero before the division

Answer (score 0):

> *I try to calculate the average of the total value inside a row*

A `0.0` can be a valid value that can exists in an array whose elements average you are calculating. This won't affect the sum of values of that array elements but if you are calculating the average of elements, then they have their influence on it. *[All the posted answers won't work if `0.0` will be a member of array.
]*. For e.g.

The first row of your `2D` array is

```
{2.30, 4.00, 5.00}
```

The average is

```
(2.30 + 4.00 + 5.00) / 3 = 3.77
```

But what happens when this row contain a member with value `0.0` :

```
{2.30, 4.00, 0.0, 5.00}  

[or may be like this - {2.30, 4.00, 5.00, 0.0}]
```

Now the average is

```
(2.30 + 4.00 + 0.0 + 5.00) / 4 = 2.83
```

Instead of having `2D` array, you can have all individual `1D` arrays which can be of different size and create a structure which will have a pointer to first element of array and, along with it, the information about size of respective array. Create an array of these structures and iterate through it and calculate the sum and average of array elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s {
    float * ptr;
    size_t size;
} ST;

float summation (float * p, size_t s) {
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        sum = sum + p[i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main (void) {
    float a1[] = {2.30, 4.00, 5.00};
    float a2[] = {3.00, 2.10, 1.00, 4.00};
    float a3[] = {1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00};
    float a4[] = {4.00, 2.50};
    float a5[] = {2.30, 4.00, 0.0, 5.00};

    ST a[] = {{a1, sizeof (a1) / sizeof (a1[0])},
              {a2, sizeof (a2) / sizeof (a2[0])},
              {a3, sizeof (a3) / sizeof (a3[0])},
              {a4, sizeof (a4) / sizeof (a4[0])},
              {a5, sizeof (a5) / sizeof (a5[0])}};

    for (size_t rows = 0; rows < sizeof (a) / sizeof (a[0]); ++rows) {
        float sum = summation (a[rows].ptr, a[rows].size);
        printf ("The Sum of row elements is =  %.2f \n", sum);
        printf ("Average %zu : %.2f\n", rows + 1, sum/a[rows].size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
% ./a.out
The Sum of row elements is =  11.30 
Average 1 : 3.77
The Sum of row elements is =  10.10 
Average 2 : 2.53
The Sum of row elements is =  15.00 
Average 3 : 3.00
The Sum of row elements is =  6.50 
Average 4 : 3.25
The Sum of row elements is =  11.30 
Average 5 : 2.83
```